# view query, with same field's name in database

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, select

i have this table

```
table a
+-------+---------+
|userid |Pid      |
+-------+---------+
|   1   |P1       |
|   1   |p2       |
|   2   |p3       |
|   2   |P4       |
+-------+---------|

table b
+-------+---------+
|userid |Pid      |
+-------+---------+
|   1   |P3       |
|   1   |p4       |
|   2   |p1       |
|   2   |P2       |
+-------+---------|
```

any idea how to take other user in table A where user in table B have pid in table B equal to other users pid in table A and  other user pid in table B equal to users pid in table A

```
select other user where
user table B.pid = other user table A.pid
and
other user B.pid= user table A.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question well, but try something like:

```
SELECT b.userid
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b
               ON a.pid = b.pid
WHERE  a.userid=someId
```

That's pretty basic SQL though, maybe you should read some tutorials.

Comment: i add "where user_id != '1'", but the SQL said the user id is ambigous, is there a way to add "where" clause if the column is ambigous without changing the table??

Comment: `Where a.user_id!=1 ` use table alias name